# Remote login on raspberry pi using sim900a module

Tags: pi-2

1. I have a Pi2 (model b), in the field with sim900A module.
   Can I access this pi2 board with remote login using TCP protocol & sim900a module.
2. I have found one module here:
   http://www.sparqee.com/products/
   I read that it has capanility to provide remote access. Not sure at this point how it does. Reading it right now.
3. But I want to do it via SIM900A module. As it is readily available. 
   Any suggestions on it.